# Parameters passed by reference can not set value

Tags: c#, string, reference

I am working on a piece of software which will simulate a browser login, and do some `GET` and `POST` requests and the server sometimes needs access to the user input to the check code.

So I made a form to let the user input the check code however when I try to pass the parameter into the check code form, it can not set the value to what the user has input in the textbox.

here is the code of `CheckcodeForm.cs`

```
public partial class CheckcodeForm : Form
{
    public string pic_url;
    public string ck;

    public CheckcodeForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CheckcodeForm(string _ck,string pic_url)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.pic_url = pic_url;
        this.ck = _ck;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = pic_url;      
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.ImageLocation = pic_url;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ck = this.textBox1.Text;
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

and here is the new `CheckcodeForm` part:

```
string _check_code = "0000";
new CheckcodeForm(_check_code,checkcodePicUrl).ShowDialog();                       
MessageBox.Show(_check_code);
```

Why do I always get the messagebox of 0000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the textbox value to the `ck` field in the form, so get it from there:

```
string _check_code = "0000";
var checkcodeForm = new CheckcodeForm(_check_code,checkcodePicUrl).ShowDialog(); 
MessageBox.Show(checkcodeForm.ck);
```

BTW, you are passing the parameter by value, not by reference. Check [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)

Comment: this is a solution but i want to know why my code didn't work i pass the _check_code(which is in the main context)to the checkcodeForm, and i reset the value in the checkcodeForm. i wonder if the _check_code and the _ck is not the same?

Comment: yes, _check_code and _ck are not the same. When you do 'this.ck = _ck'; you are assigning the value of _ck to 'this.ck'. But those variables are indepedent, and they can have different values. If you later assign a different value to 'this.ck', the other variable wont change.